# Docker - Can i have two FROM commands?

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I want to be able to set up an image that has both the Ubuntu and the node images.

I started with the Ubuntu and downloaded all the necessary programs, including node.js.

Here is the latest Dockerfile i created, out of the many i tried:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y software-properties-common

#install freecad
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:freecad-maintainers/freecad-daily
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y freecad-daily

#install utils
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt install -y git

RUN apt install -y python3-distutils

#install node
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y git-core curl build-essential openssl libssl-dev \
 && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git \
 && cd node \
 && ./configure \
 && make \
 && sudo make install


COPY . . 
 
RUN npm install

CMD ["node","server.js"]
```

Can i use two different FROM commands, for building my image?

The one to download ubuntu, and the other to download node.js?

Comment: Does this help? - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from

Comment: Yes, you can use two different FROM commands for building your image. This is commonly used in [multistaged builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)